# Will headers from MultipartFormDataStreamProvider match order of LocalFileName

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to save files from a POST and I want to ensure the files on disk match the filenames in the POST.

```
MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider); 

List<string> fileNames = provider.FileData.Select(entry => entry.LocalFileName).ToList();
List<string> sentNames = provider.FileData.Select(entry => entry.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName).ToList();
```

Can I trust that fileNames and sentNames will be in the same order?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not do a few tests and see?

Comment: I did some rudimentary tests and they have been in order so far.... Just looking for a double check before I put this out into the world.